# Nth-child confusion once the text is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using javascript to change my website language. Also I'm using CSS `nth-child` to design my menu as you can see in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/PowKZmV).

Once the text is changed to english its works fine, but once the text changes to hebrew the design based on nth-child is failing on the first child of the menu.

How can I fix the first child design to be in the correct order like english text?

```
ul li:nth-child(1) a:before
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a:after
{
    background-color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a:before
{
    background-color: #00e2ff;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a:after
{
    background-color: #89ff00;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) a:before
{
    background-color: purple;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) a:after
{
    background-color: palevioletred;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) a:before
{
    background-color: darkblue;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) a:after
{
    background-color: dimgrey;
}
ul li:nth-child(5) a:before
{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a:after
{
    background-color: #990000;
}
ul li a:hover:before, ul li a:hover:after
{
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: `display: inline-block` on the list items work. https://codepen.io/sparxia/pen/eYmEJyB

Comment: @ManojKumar Thank you, that worked! please write answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this style, you need to add `display: inline-block` to the `a` element. I've also removed style `line-height: 70px;` for testing:

```
.navigation-bar li a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  /*line-height: 70px;*/
  transition: 0.2s ease color;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block; /* add this style */
}
```